# query output shows ##,###,### instead of right output

Tags: postgresql

I am working on one project in which, query output gives ##,###,### instead of right values.

according to requirement we calculate the time period and display it in separate table.

this is query I am using as calculation

```sql
select (to_char((coalesce(11808000,0) - (coalesce(3562.66,0) - (coalesce(1800,0) + (coalesce(1800,0))))),'FM99,999,999'))::character varying as mytest
```

so if I run this one, it will give output properly, but the seperate table what we use to display output is giving wrong values. can any one help me with this ??

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=4270f03ae3db590da5a1d64af38108dd - but in general the output `##,###,###` means your format mask was too short to handle the actual number. You need to increase the number of digits there, e.g. `FM999,999,999`

Comment: Please add only a tag for the Postgres version you are **really** using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output looks like `##,###,###`, the number is too big for the format.

Use a longer format string like

```
FM99,999,999,999
```

Comment: can you please check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271593/results-are-varying-with-same-query